How to find a text name of Tool classes in LangChain?
The LangChain documentation states that it offers integrations with various services and APIs to let agents interact with the world. These agents are mostly available under langchain_community or langchain_core packages.
Code examples show that tools can be loaded through their class names like ArxivQueryRun or using the load_tools function like below:
from langchain_community.agent_toolkits.load_tools import load_tools

tools = load_tools(['arxiv'])

print(tools[0].invoke("StackOverflow"))

To me, load_tools function seems much more straightforward as it provides a single way to retrieve all LangChain tools. The catch, however, is that you are required to know text names of tool classes like the example of 'arxiv' and ArxivQueryRun.
Is there a way to get the text name of any tool class so that we can pass it to the load_tools function?

After scouring the API reference, I discovered the function that prints all tool names' string representation:
from langchain_community.agent_toolkits.load_tools import get_all_tool_names

get_all_tool_names()[:10]

Output:
['sleep',
 'wolfram-alpha',
 'google-search',
 'google-search-results-json',
 'searx-search-results-json',
 'bing-search',
 'metaphor-search',
 'ddg-search',
 'google-lens',
 'google-serper']

